# Can't insert data forms to sql server using electron

Tags: sql-server-2008, electron

Whenever I click the submit button, it won't transfer the data to mssql.

It seems like it only works on hard-coded query with onload events without the web forms.

HTML

```
<form>
First Name:<input type="text" id="first_name" required="true"/>
Last Name: <input type="text" id="last_name" required="true"/> 
<button onclick="formdata()"> Submit  </button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function formdata(){
var sql = require('mssql');
var config = {
    userName: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'server',
    database: 'database',
    options: {
         instanceName: 'instancename'
            , encrypt: false
    } 
};   
sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        var request = new sql.Request();
       var fn = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
       var ln = document.getElementById('last_name').value;
          request.query('execute sp_tmp_name fn,ln');
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

I finally work it out.  I included the ipcmain and ipcrenderer part to make it work.

Forms js

```
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer; 
function formdata(event){
  event.preventDefault() 
       let fn = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
       let ln = document.getElementById('last_name').value;
          ipcRenderer.send('form-submission', fn,ln) 
      //pass ipcRenderer data to ipcmain 
    }
```

Main js

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron')
 ........
  ipcMain.on('form-submission', function (event, first_name,last_name) {
    event.preventDefault() 
   var sql = require('mssql');

   const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool({
    user: 'xxxx',
    password: 'xxxx',
    server: 'xxxx',
    database: 'xxxx',
    options: {
         instanceName: 'xxxx'
            , encrypt: false
         }  
   })
   var conn = pool;
   conn.connect().then(function () {
   var request = new sql.Request(conn);
    request.query("execute sp_tmp_name_sample" +" "+ first_name +","+last_name).then(function (recordset) {
        console.log(recordset);
        conn.close();
      })
    .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            conn.close();
      });
   });
})
```

HTML

```
<form action="#" method="post" name="ipcForm">
First Name:<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required="true"/>
Last Name: <input type="text" id="last_name"  name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required="true"/> 
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="formdata(event)"/>
</form>            
<script src="forms.js"></script>
```